# javascript:Shifting the <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, indexing

I have three `<li>`

```
<li id="li_93_n:90" class="liGrid" data-upindex="" data-itemindex="'9001'" data-itemid="'93_n:90'" style="">
blah1</li>
<li id="li_50_n:90" class="liGrid" data-upindex="" data-itemindex="'9002'" data-itemid="'50_n:90'" style="">
blah2</li>
<li id="li_91_n:90" class="liGrid" data-upindex="" data-itemindex="'9003'" data-itemid="'91_n:90'" style="">
blah3</li>
```

And now I have to insert a one more `<li>` at second postion and have to shift **blah2** and **blah3**

```
<li id="li_80_n:90" class="liGrid" data-upindex="" data-itemindex="'9002'" data-itemid="'80_n:90'" style="">
blah-blah</li>
```

and change `data-itemindex` of **blah2** and **blah3** from **9002 to 9003 *and* 9003 to 9004**

In short terms I have to insert new `<li>` in between and shift from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$("li:first")` will get the first li tag,then you can use `.after()` for add `li` after the the selected tag.

```
$("li:first").after($("<li/>", {
    class: "liGrid",
    "data-itemindex": "9002",
    html: "blah2"
}));
var itemIndex = 9001;
$("li").each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr("data-itemindex", itemIndex + i);
});
```

Then you need to reassign the itemindex of every li tags

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7QA3p/6/)

**Edit**
USe this code for dynamic postions

```
var position = 2;
$("li:gt(" + (position-1) + ")").each(function (i) {
    var dataValue = parseInt($(this).attr("data-itemindex"))+1;

    $(this).attr("data-itemindex", dataValue);
});
$("li").eq(position-1).after($("<li/>", {
    class: "liGrid",
    "data-itemindex": parseInt($("li").eq(position-1).attr("data-itemindex")) + 1,
    html: "blah122"
}));
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7QA3p/11/)

Comment: new `<li>` data-index is dynamic it can be any, above  my question is just an example for second postion,it can be first ,second or any postion

Comment: i have to swap according to new `data-itemindex` of new `<li>`

Comment: working but actually there are already more `<li>` are present in my page header. the new `<li>` is added in header <li> pairs , not in the those `<li>` where i want.